# Escopo equivalente ao @Stateless no CDI

Tags: injeção-de-dependência, cdi, ejb, annotation

Estou migrando as anotações **EJB** da minha aplicação para **CDI** e tenho algumas dúvidas:

- Qual é o escopo equivalente ao `@Stateless` do EJB no CDI?
- O `@ResquestScoped` faria um comportamento equivalente?
- Eu fiz testes utilizando `@Stateless` injetando com CDI usando `@Inject`, isso é correto?

Estou migrando uma classe de serviços que apenas recebe as requisições do meu managedBean e passa as informações para a classe de persistência e que não precisa manter seu escopo vivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salvo com o uso de alguma extensão, não existe nada 100% equivalente no CDI.

Apesar disso, o RequestScoped pode servir bem para muitos casos, lembrando que EJBs também controlam transações (criaram novas anotações para transações no CDI 1.1 ou 1.2) e têm um ciclo de vida que reaproveita instâncias (de um pool) em vez de criar novas. Se essas pequenas diferenças não atrapalharem, tudo bem.

O uso de Inject, a princípio (sem ver o código), parece correto.

Este artigo http://blog.dblevins.com/2012/11/cdi-when-to-break-out-ejbs.html indica funcionalidades que existem no EJB mas não no CDI, mas não inclui novidades criadas após o CDI 1.0.

Comment: Excelente resposta, vou aguardar mais um dia para ver as próximas respostas, mas já adianto meus agradecimentos e caso ninguém responda algo melhor a recompensa é sua. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

O que melhor que se enquadra para substituição do `@Stateless` utilizando o CDI é o `@RequestScoped`.

O conceito do [stateless](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocolo_sem_estado) é *considerar cada requisição como uma transação independente que não está relacionada a qualquer requisição anterior*.

Já o [@RequestScoped](http://eumaismais.com.br/2016/03/31/jsf-entendendo-e-utilizando-corretamente-os-escopos/) *ele funciona como um simples HTTP request, é descartado ao fim de cada requisição, o ManagedBean não manterá seu estado entre as solicitações/requisições HTTP que o usuário fizer.*

Por isso a melhor opção é **ele próprio**.

Parar complementar, eu costumo utilizar bastante o [@ViewScoped](http://eumaismais.com.br/2016/03/31/jsf-entendendo-e-utilizando-corretamente-os-escopos/) pois ele mantém o estado enquanto o usuário se mantém na página, sendo um meio termo entre `@RequestScoped` e `@SessionScoped`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!